# Import GPS SINEX (for velocity analysis) into Sarscape or processing with others software

Tags: data, gps, remote-sensing, envi, radar

I try to import GPS snx. into Sarscape 5.2 (use GPS Import tool) and getting error

```
  115)   )   gps_type : [sinex]
  116)   )   generate_kml : [OK]
  117)   )   generate_shape : [OK]
  118)   )   shape_measure_in_los : [OK]
  119)   )   orbit_interp_val : [100]
  120)   )   ****************************
```

and

```
 125)   )   ************* ERROR 
  126)   )   
  127)   )   * Software version       : SARscape ENVI  5.2.0 Aug 17 2015  W64
  128)   )   * Actual step            :  Import GPS-SINEX
  129)   )   * Source File            : source\import_export\sars_import_gps.cpp
  130)   )   * Error Line             : 302
  131)   )   * Error Code             : 280021
  132)   )   * Primary Error Code     : 28
  133)   )   * Primary Error Des      : GPS IMPORT ERROR
  134)   )   * Secondary Error Code   : 20
  135)   )   * Secondary Error Des    : NOT ALL SITE/IDS IN SOLUTION/ESTIMATE BLOCK HAVE ALL VELOCITY ESTIMATES
  136)   )   * Error Parameter        :
```

Data i took from here: [webigs.ign.fr](http://webigs.ign.fr/) And this error for other data

```
   145)   )   * Software version       : SARscape ENVI  5.2.0 Aug 17 2015  W64
  146)   )   * Actual step            :  Import GPS-SINEX
  147)   )   * Source File            : source\import_export\sars_import_gps.cpp
  148)   )   * Error Line             : 290
  149)   )   * Error Code             : 280018
  150)   )   * Primary Error Code     : 28
  151)   )   * Primary Error Des      : GPS IMPORT ERROR
  152)   )   * Secondary Error Code   : 17
  153)   )   * Secondary Error Des    : NON-VALID PARAMETER FOUND IN SOLUTION/ESTIMATE BLOCK
  154)   )   * Error Parameter        :
```

Maybe there are other software capable of importing the snx. or gsi.? Where can I get .gsi data GPS?

Comment: Can you add the download link corresponding to your input data?

Comment: Unfortunately, since the site is impossible, because the address does not contain an individual session, you can find data on their own here http://webigs.ign.fr/en/gdc/product/search/ choose SINEX, or download, I put on file sharing example data. http://depositfiles.com/files/ya17nwubk. To unzip data i use 7-zip

Comment: I check sir16027.snx and there is no velocity parameter (VELX, VELY, VELZ). I think this is the problem. I don't know if this parameter is required. I have check it with ftp://ftp.glonass-iac.ru/GENERAL/FORMAT/SINEX.TXT

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a bit strange. I try to data from UNVACO and I will give you to know about the results.

Comment: I download sinex and vel files from UNVACO and getting the same result...

Comment: Have you check version of sinex? i have just find help for sarscape 5.1 but it don't speak about format version compatibilities ... 2.00 (24 May 2002), 2.01 (24 Mar 2005), and 2.02 (1 Dec 2006)

Comment: Hmm i also have 5.1.2. sarscape and 5.0. i check all (from UNVACO version SNX 2.01 )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32815/discussion-between-geostonemarten-and-wonder).

Comment: next disccuss in chat